# Animate drawing arc with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have drawn an arc using:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *stripePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [arcColor set];
    [stripePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:clockwise];
    stripePath.lineWidth = arcWidth;
    stripePath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    stripePath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    [stripePath stroke];
}
```

Now I want to animate this arc by the angle.

I am trying it with something like:

```
angle = startAngle;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     angle = endAngle;
                     [stripePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:angle clockwise:clockwise];
                     [stripePath stroke];
}];
```

However no animation is being displayed on screen. How to animate the arc with the angle as the changing variable? Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

May [MHRadialProgressView](https://github.com/mehfuzh/MHRadialProgressView)  will help you to animating arc by specific angle.

Comment: I followed your link and solved my issue. Though you do not provide the code, I still accept yours as answer. Please vote up my answer if anyone saw my code, thanks!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

Below code achieved my goal:

```
UIBezierPath *stripePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[arcColor set];
stripePath.lineWidth = arcWidth;
stripePath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
stripePath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
[stripePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:clockwise];

[_stripeLayer setPath:stripePath.CGPath];
[_stripeLayer setStrokeColor:arcColor.CGColor];
[_stripeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[_stripeLayer setLineWidth:arcWidth];
[_stripeLayer setStrokeStart:0.0];
[_stripeLayer setStrokeEnd:1.0];
[_stripeLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapRound];
[_stripeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineCapRound];

if ([_stripeLayer superlayer]) {
    [_stripeLayer removeAllAnimations];
    [_stripeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

}
[self.layer addSublayer:_stripeLayer];

CABasicAnimation *animateStrokEnd = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animateStrokEnd.duration = 1;
animateStrokEnd.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animateStrokEnd.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
[_stripeLayer addAnimation:animateStrokEnd forKey:nil];
```

Comment: what is *stripeLayer* in this case ? is it - CAShapeLayer ?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Note that it is not necessary to remove and add the layer again to the hierarchy, it is enough to remove the animation and create a new one